# Android app crashing on installing

Tags: android, debugging, installation, crash

My app is throwing the "Unfortunately, app has stopped" on installing an upgrade to my current app. I have crashlytics installed but it seems it does not have  chance to initialize before my crash. I cannot debug the app because its on custom hardware and I tried adding Toast messages in my OnCreate() in my launcher activity and in my Application class but I don't see any of them. Not sure how to debug from here....

Comment: Do you have access to emulator?

Comment: well I suppose I could run in emulator, but my app relies on custom hardware that my android device is connected to.

Comment: Dont worry about the hardware in emulator. Your app may crash in other parts. If your app wont start without that hardware, change your codes to check if that hardware is available and then debug it using emulator. As a personal guess,most of crashes on new updates relates to database structure or invalid casting of element types.

Comment: I'll try an emulator but I tried installing on one of my phones and I could not replicate the issue.....and yes for me as well, its usually a db upgrade issue but I disabled all db upgrade code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps,

1.Add your android Sdk's adb tools path to your computer's Environment Virable "Path".
Ex:

```
Path = C:\Android\android_sdk\platform-tools
```

2.And then, try to use adb command to take the dumpstate log

```
adb shell dumpstate > C:\dumpstate_installer_crash.txt
```

The dumpstate log should be save in your computer "C:\dumpstate_installer_crash.txt" path.

Then, to check and analyse this log, it may help to find some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I installed "LogCat Extreme" from the Google Play Store.  to read the logcat on my device and was able to find the issue.